# Nice way of resetting a variable

Tags: c#

I've been finding myself doing this pattern, for large pre-existing objects we want to modify slightly to pass down to another call, but don't want to copy but don't want the caller to see the change:

```
ResultType f(T x, TLarge config) {
    var oldVal = config.blah; // 1st line of boilerplate
    config.blah = "New Value"; // 2nd line of boilerplate
    try {
        return g(config);
    }
    finally
    {
        config.blah = oldVal; // 3rd line of boilerplate
    }
}
```

This gets a bit messy particularly when there's more than one variable to change.

Is there a nice way to wrap this up into a pattern? I tried using `using` and sticking a reference as a member to an IDisposable struct and resetting on close but that didn't work as references can't be members.

A lot of the types I'm temporarily modifying are strings and ints so this needs to work with value types.

Comment: As an aside, your last sentence *looks* like it means you think string is a value type - it's not, it's a reference type. It might also be worth clarifying that you're not actually *modifying the string or int* - you're modifying an object that *contains* a string or int as a property or field.

Comment: While you could write a method to handle this to some extent, you'd need to pass in the old value, the new value, a delegate to reset the value, and a delegate to execute in the try block - at which point the code looks significantly more complicated than the simple try/finally block.

Comment: Just joking. Pretty sure with reflection you can do something like this. `tempChange(config, "blah", newValue, {code})`. Even works with multiple fields with some modifications.

Comment: is `ResultType` fixed/always the same in this context? or can it also vary from context to context?

Comment: Have you considered cloning, to avoid the need for the revert step?

Comment: @JonSkeet yes good point I had confused myself there. It doesn't really matter if it's a value or a reference type. Thinking about it more to attempt the "using" approach I need to hold a reference to the (reference or value) and of course C# won't allow this as variables themselves (not what they point to) die at the end of the scope.

Comment: @mjwills: Yes. The whole approach needs a redesign, but cloning is not reasonable currently, I'd be cloning many hundreds of variables just to change one or two. Better approach is probably to make the getters virtual in hindsight at the very least.